# Problems with session variables

Tags: php, mysql, session

```
<?php
session_name('MYSESSION');
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/~cgreenheld/');
session_start();
?>              

<?php
    if($_SESSION['authorisation'] == 'knownuser') {
       echo '<ul class="log">';
       echo '<li><h4>You are logged in "'.$_SESSION['user'].'"</h4></li>';
       echo '<li><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>';
       echo "</ul>";
     } else {
        echo "<h4>You are not logged in</h4>";
     }

     if($_SESSION['authorisation'] == 'knownuser') {
        echo "<ul>";
        echo "<li><h4>You are logged in and already have an account</h4></li>";
        echo '<li><a href="index.php">Return Home</a></li>';
        echo "</ul>";
       } else {

        echo "<form method='post' action='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."'>";
        echo '<fieldset class="login">';
        echo "<h2>Login</h2>";
        echo "<ul>";
        echo '<li><label for="Username"> Username: </label> <input type="text" name="Username" id="Username"></li>';
        echo '<li><label for="Password"> Password: </label> <input type="password" name="Password" id="Password"></li>';
        echo '<li><input type="submit" value="Login"><li>';
        echo "</ul>";
        echo "</fieldset>";
        echo "</form>";
       }
       if ((isset($_POST['Password'])) && $_POST['Password'] != "") {                   
         $conn= new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world"); //changed for the sake of this question

         $match_Username = '%';
         $match_Password ='';

         if(isset($_POST['Password'])) {
            $clean_Password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['Password']);
            $match_Password =  sha1($clean_Password);
         }

        if (isset($_POST['Username'])) {
            $clean_Username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['Username']);
            $match_Username = $clean_Username;
        }

        echo $query = "select * from User WHERE Username = '$match_Username' and Password = '$match_Password';";
        $result = $conn->query($query);

        if ($result->num_rows==1) {
            $_SESSION['authorisation'] = 'knownuser';
            $_SESSION['user'] = $_POST['Username'];
            header("Location: index.php");
            exit;
        } else {
            $_SESSION['authorisation'] = 'unknownuser';
            header("Location: error.php");
            exit;
            }               
        }
```

The two php tabs are to show in this version that they are from different files. I have made a user log in, and when the user logs in, i want it to redirect to the front page, and I want it to display "You are logged in *insert user name here*. Atm I only get an empty string, and I'm not sure why. Help anybody? I also know I haven't santizied my inputs and so. And also I keep getting this error about the authorisation session variable
    [22-Aug-2012 11:32:02] PHP Notice:  Undefined index:  authorisation in /devel/cgreenheld/projects/Asgn1/login.php on line 23
    [22-Aug-2012 11:32:02] PHP Notice:  Undefined index:  authorisation in /devel/cgreenheld/projects/Asgn1/login.php on line 46
    I'm not quite sure what that's about, but if someone could clarify that for me, it would be great.

The lines that are going wrong for 23 and 46 are:

```
if($_SESSION['authorisation'] == 'knownuser') {
```

This piece of code here

Comment: I don't see a `session_start()`

Comment: It is there, I just left it out of the code example. In there now. It is in both files.

Comment: What is the code in lines 23 and 46 in your code? Can you please post it with few closest lines so we can see where the problem happens?

Comment: What is this filename?  Is it index.php?

Comment: The first set of php tags under session is index.php, the second set of php tags is in a separate file called login.php

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I found the problem to question. I didn't have an isset for session user, so it wasn't checking for it. When I started checking for it, It displayed the username. Thank you for everyones help, and the help on the authorisation errors I was having.

Answer (score 0):

As musa pointed out, you are mission `session_start()` function. Your notices suggest that `authorisation` key does not exist in `$_SESSION`, that too indicate a uninitialized session.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a problem with session start. I would assume that in `session_set_cookie_params(0, '/~cgreenheld/');` 
there is something wrong with second param. Your page must have an url like www.example.com/~cgreenheld/ with setting like yours. Or it is possible that you do not include index.php where session start is located.

Comment: This is all on a server we use at university. It's what we're suppose to use, so I don't think it's anything to do with that.

Comment: Well, if you open your page with url like www.university-server.com/~cgreenheld/login.php - than there is no problem, of course. But if it is like www.university-server.com/login.php, for instance, second parameter is wrong. Because your session cookie will be sent only to pages located at www.university-server.com/~cgreenheld/

Answer (score 0):

Well your errors are coming from the fact that $_SESSION['authorisation'] is not set and thus does not exist.  Since it doesn't exist and you are calling upon it in lines 23 and 46, you are getting those errors.  As a note, it might be better practice to test whether these vars are set before you call them, that way if they are empty or not set you won't get those errors.

`if(!empty($_SESSION['authorisation']))`

So the problem is that the sessions vars are not being set in login.php.  I believe part of your issue may be coming from your header() calls in your conditionals after your sql query.  headers need to be sent before any html is written, so when you write your form up top and then send headers afterwards, the header will not work.  Try changing the action of your form to a separate page (say "authenticate.php") and move your sql query and session setting to there.  Don't forget to session_start() at the top and be sure there is no html before your header()s.